# how to test for empty mongodb query in pymong

Tags: pymongo

How do I test for a query with no results in pymongo?

```
 x = collection.find( { "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ {"template":"template3.1"} , {"type" : "gift"} ] }, {"to":"test@test.com"} ] } )
```

Can test if `x` has returned nothing before doing something with the data?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cursor Method [count()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor-count) to check the number of documents in the cursor.

```
if x.count()>0:
    //Use Cursor
```